# When I download Heroku Toolbelt, it downloads as "Unknown"

Tags: macos, heroku, download, heroku-toolbelt

So when I double click on the file it opens it up in TextEdit... Not sure if there's another place besides https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ that I should try downloading it from or if it's possible I'm doing it wrong?

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6.8

Thank you,
Chet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Rename it to heroku-toolbelt.pkg

2) run in terminal:

```
cd Downloads #or wherever you downloaded it
md5 heroku-toolbelt.pkg
```

You should see:

```
MD5 (heroku-toolbelt.pkg) = c637cd30d6485a893dacd2a680d05c9c
```

3) If the MD5 matches mine, run it.